# Sublime Text C++ не компилирует

Tags: text, sublime-text, c++

пытаюсь скомпилировать на СБ вот такой текст

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout<<"butthurt"<<endl;
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

но в консоли СБ никаких сообщений об ошибках нет и экзешник не появляется. до этого писало ошибку

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec
> can't decode byte 0xcf in position 4:
> ordinal not in range(128)

исправил с помощью [этого](http://onofflife.blogspot.com/2011/12/sublime-text-2-part-3-cc.html) поста. теперь же в консоли тишина. помогите пожалуйста

Comment: в пути к файлу нет русских символов?

Comment: файл лежит в корне диска

Comment: "а если добавить exe в конец E:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe?"
то же самое

Answer (score 1):

А уверенны, что у Вашего компилятора есть файл `conio.h` и функция `getch`? Эти вещи устарели лет десять назад и работали в очень древних компиляторах (Borland C++ 5.5). Просто выбросите эти две строки. А заодно и свой древний учебник.

Comment: из консоли винды все компилируется как надо

Comment: @melodicwing: тем же компилятором?

Comment: да, g++ от MinGW

Comment: Видимо потому, что с консоли Вы используете свой компилятор, а sublime ни сном не духом о нем. Нужно как минимум прописать путь к компилятору и сделать свой `*.sublime_build`.

Да, и забыть о древнем компиляторе.

Comment: @melodicwing: хм, в g++ есть динозавр `conio.h`? не знал.

Comment: ["E:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"] вот кусок из моего *.sublime_build

а вот то, что вводил в консоли: E:\MinGW\bin\g++ test.cpp -o E:\test

Comment: Вот такой код компилируется?

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
      cout<<"butthurt"<<endl;
      return 0;
    }

Comment: нет, все так же тихо в консоли

Comment: а если добавить exe в конец `E:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe`?